# How to remove nextall and prevall css color in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was trying to set active color when an element is clicked on, then if another is click it will remove the color from the previous and next to set color on the new clicked element. Below code was able to set color when click on the div element but I don't remove the color on the previous and next element when another one is clicked.

Please i neeed help

```js
$('.listers').click(function(event) {
  var evt = $(this);
  var kids = $(event.target).children();
  var len = kids.css('color', 'green');
  var e_type = $(evt).attr('data-event-attribute');
  $('#collection-type').val(e_type);
  $('.listers .listlogo > .fa').children().prevAll().css('color', '#F4BD00');
  $('.listers .listlogo > .fa', this).len;
  $('.listers .listlogo > .fa').children().nextAll().css('color', '#F4BD00');

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="listers" data-event-attribute="1">
  <span class="listlogo"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>Data 1
</div>

<div class="listers" data-event-attribute="1">
  <span class="listlogo"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span> Data 2
</div>

<div class="listers" data-event-attribute="1">
  <span class="listlogo"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span> Data 3
</div>
```

Comment: Use classes as `addClass` / `removeClass` are easier and cleaner.  You could use `.siblings()` rather than nextAll/prevAll.   `.fa` doesn't have any `children()` so there's nothing to apply it to and they don't have any siblings so not sure why you're applying at the .fa level.  Try this:   `$(".listers").click(function() { $(".listers").removeClass("active");$(this).addClass("active"); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I proposed another solution using `addClass/removeClass`, and you can manage the css using the class **active**

```js
$('.listers').click(function(event) {
  var evt = $(this);
  var e_type = $(evt).attr('data-event-attribute');
  $('#collection-type').val(e_type);
  $('.listers').removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.active .fa {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="listers" data-event-attribute="1">
  <span class="listlogo"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>Data 1
</div>

<div class="listers" data-event-attribute="1">
  <span class="listlogo"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span> Data 2
</div>

<div class="listers" data-event-attribute="1">
  <span class="listlogo"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span> Data 3
</div>
```